# Generating Previews

Tags: epub, indesign

I have ~1500 generated `.epub` files and their indesign files

I need a script or program to generate previews for these EPUBs. 
Preview could be in jpeg or epub format.

By preview I mean first 10 pages of the book as indicated by indesign's pagination system.
I use both Mac and Windows machines,

Comment: What do you consider a preview (first N pages?). What platform/OS are you working on?

Comment: Is there any consistency in the formatting of the InDesign files or the epubs? If they're done with a template, it should be fairly easy to put together a script that would grab the first n sections (eg, cover, copyright page, introduction, chapter 1). If the files aren't consistent or well-tagged, then it'll be trickier.

Comment: Do you have some indication (based on CSS, or the indesign files) of where page 10 ends? A normal EPUB page contents varies wildly and depends on the resolution of the device it is viewed upon, the font size, margins etc.

Answer (score 1):

The ePub file does not contain any information about the InDesign pagination -- that information is all left behind when the ePub file is generated. So your only possible way to do that is inside InDesign.

Inside InDesign it will be either point-click-clic-click ...a few thousand times or you script it with an additional tool like [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/) that can open, select the first 10 pages and then save the selection to ePub and re-do-it in the next file...

If your files have a lot of consistency -- almost the same structure -- and you can live with separating the first chapter, for example, then you can open them up (unzip), and edit with "sed" or "awk" to have a smaller set containing only a certain specific part.